# Splitting a csv to muliple lists suing java code

Tags: java, list, csv

[I have the following csv file with the tupe of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvomd.png)

I want to **split** the csv data using java into lists:

1. list one should contain the emails of the users;
2. list two should contain the multiple values i.e : entitlements of the user .

How to proceed using the `split` function ?

Comment: Please show some code that you've tried so far... Splitting by two different delimiters might become a pain (you have data separated by , and " in your example)...

Comment: I think might need some parsing logic to deal with the fact that a comma sometimes means a delimiter, and sometimes means actual data.

Comment: better to use a csvReader class

Comment: cant it be achieved with regular expressions ?